# Clap sound detection in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am just curious. I am making a very simple game and I want to include the game logic when the user claps (like do the loud sound). Is it possible in libgdx?

Comment: I want it to record the sound every frame and get the amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

There is `AudioRecorder` interface in libgdx for the same. You can access PCM data from the microphone on a PC or Android phone.

```
int samples = 44100;
boolean isMono = true;
AudioRecorder recorder = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(samples, isMono);
```

This will create an `AudioRecorder` with a sampling rate of 44.1khz, in mono mode. If the recorder couldn't be created, a GdxRuntimeException will be thrown.

Samples can be read as 16-bit signed PCM:

```
int seconds = 5;
final short[] data = new short[samples * seconds];
recorder.readSamples(data, 0, data.length);
```

Audio recording is not supported in the JavaScript/WebGL backend.

Comment: but how to record the sound every frame?

Comment: According to me in libgdx, you can't get amplitude of sound every frame however in android it  can possible and can be used by interfacing.

Comment: Usually, you read microphone in a separated thread, do some audio analysis (RMS on a predefined window) and fire event to the GLThread by using postRunnable https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading.